# Powershell outputting malformed filenames

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, powershell

I'm using this command:

```
Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} > file_names.txt
```

to print the file names in my current directory to a file (without final extensions). Opening the file names in notepad shows the file names properly printed. Simple enough, yes. Cool.

My problem is that on reading the file names in with a BufferedReader in Java, the file names are coming up malformed. For example,

20100916_090350_S1_1_auto gain test_1.Rad    comes up as

ÿþ2 0 1 0 0 9 1 6 _ S 1 _ 1 _ a u t o   g a i n   t e s t _ 1 . R a d

(the .Rad extension should be there, there was another extension after it that I wanted removed)

I assume this is some type of silly windows encoding issue. Unfortunately, I know nothing about these sorts of things. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell by default emits Unicode, and the characters you see at the beginning are called BOM (Byte Order Mark). You can either force Java to read Unicode, or force Powershell to output other encoding, preferrably `default` or `OEM` with the help of `Out-File` with parameter `-Encoding`. So to summarize try this:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName} | Out-File -Encoding default file_names.txt
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! So I figured out that I needed to get rid of the BOM a while ago, but spent the last half hour failing to do that. I hadn't specified any encoding so I assumed it was using default. Why does telling it to use default encoding do this when it wasn't doing that before?

Comment: Well, the `>` syntax is just a syntactic sugar for `| Out-File`, and according to [the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) default encoding for Out-File is Unicode. For example in Polish "Default" would be the Code Page 1250, and "OEM" would be old DOS Code Page 852. I don't recommend diving into the quirks of OEM/ANSI encoding, just try to use Unicode or UTF-8 whenever possible to provide compatibility with modern international-aware environments.

Comment: I understand that, what I am confused about is that I did not originally specify what to encode it as. The files ended up encoded as Big-Endian (whatever that is), and so I assumed that was the default; that's why I didn't bother trying the default encoding. And when I tried the UTF-8 encoding, I could only get the encoding with the BOM. I'm just curious as to why it didn't default to the "default" setting. Also, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ASCII output probably.
Use this:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$_.BaseName} | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -FilePath file_names.txt
```